# Pyspark most reliable way to verify column type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, type-conversion, apache-spark-sql

If I read data from a CSV, all the columns will be of "String" type by default. Generally I inspect the data using the following functions which gives an overview of the data and its types

- df.dtypes
- df.show()
- df.printSchema()
- df.distinct().count()
- df.describe().show()

But, if there is a column that I believe is of a particular type e.g. Double, I cannot be sure if all the values are double if I don't have business knowledge and because

1- I cannot see all the values (millions of unique values)
2- If I explicitly cast it to double type, spark quietly converts the type without throwing any exception and the values which are not double are converted to "null" - for example

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType.

changedTypedf = df_original.withColumn('label', df_control_trip['id'].cast(DoubleType()))
```

What could be the best way to confirm the type of column then?

Comment: When [reading from CSV](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv) you can set `inferSchema=True` and it will try to figure out the types for each column,

Answer (score 0):

In Scala Dataframe has field "schema", guess, in Python the same:

```
df.schema.fields.find( _.name=="label").get.dataType
```